# Два for в одну строчку

Tags: python, list, for

```py
res = []
for k in str:
    for j in str1:
        if k == j:
            res.append(k)
```

Возможно ли записать это в одну строчку?

Comment: скушали второй for :)

Comment: Ну ладно, отсутствие break всё усложняет... Тогда вот так `res = [k for k in str for j in str1 if k == j]`

Comment: Главное сначала подумайте что вам лучше читать и понимать нормальный for или ужатый в одну строку... P.S. без 2 for можно обойтись

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` - плохое название для переменной, оно перекрывает встроенный класс питона. Поэтому у меня будут `str1` и `str2`.

Второй цикл `for` вообще не нужен, его можно заменить оператором `in`. Вариант со списковым включением:

```
res = [k for k in str1 if k in str2]
```

Вариант через множества вообще без `for`, но он подходит только в случае, если символы в строках не повторяются и порядок следования символов в результате не важен (и если на выходе нужен именно список, нужно потом результат преобразовать через `list()`):

```
res = set(str1) & set(str2)
```

Ну и на закуску "функциональный" вариант с `filter` (аналог первого варианта по сути):

```
res = list(filter(str2.__contains__, str1))
```

Comment: Вариант с set частенько будет давать другой результат.

Comment: @Эникейщик А, точно, не подумал

Comment: Но хотя на самом деле неизвестно, что именно требуется. Может, на самом деле, именно это и надо :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Добавил в ответ пояснение )

Comment: Вариант без второго цикла for не эквивалентен коду из вопроса (я тоже сперва написал такой в комментарии, но потом удалил)